# How to set width as percent on collection_check_boxes?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to set width as percent on `collection_check_boxes`? Since there are 7 checkboxes I want each one to be 18%.

Problem is now if I set it to 18% the background-color becomes 18% of itself instead of where it is vs. larger container.

**Ruby**

```
<div class="challenge-do-on">
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :committed, Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES, :downcase, :to_s %>
</div>
```

**HTML Output**

```
<div class="challenge-do-on">

<span><label for="challenge_committed_sun"><input type="checkbox" value="sun" checked="checked" name="challenge[committed][]" id="challenge_committed_sun"><label class="collection_check_boxes"for="challenge_committed_sun">Sun</label></label></span>

<span><label for="challenge_committed_mon"><input type="checkbox" value="mon" checked="checked" name="challenge[committed][]" id="challenge_committed_mon"><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="challenge_committed_mon">Mon</label></label></span>

<span><label for="challenge_committed_tue"><input type="checkbox" value="tue" checked="checked" name="challenge[committed][]" id="challenge_committed_tue"><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="challenge_committed_tue">Tue</label></label></span>

<span><label for="challenge_committed_wed"><input type="checkbox" value="wed" checked="checked" name="challenge[committed][]" id="challenge_committed_wed"><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="challenge_committed_wed">Wed</label></label></span>

<span><label for="challenge_committed_thu"><input type="checkbox" value="thu" checked="checked" name="challenge[committed][]" id="challenge_committed_thu"><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="challenge_committed_thu">Thu</label></label></span>

<span><label for="challenge_committed_fri"><input type="checkbox" value="fri" checked="checked" name="challenge[committed][]" id="challenge_committed_fri"><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="challenge_committed_fri">Fri</label></label></span>

<span><label for="challenge_committed_sat"><input type="checkbox" value="sat" checked="checked" name="challenge[committed][]" id="challenge_committed_sat"><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="challenge_committed_sat">Sat</label></label></span>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the checkboxes to be "in-line" so they are all on the same horizontal line, taking up an even amount of space? Is this using Rails? Are you using anything like Bootstrap?

Comment: Yea rails and bootstrap. Maybe the latter is causing the problem. I want each box to be 18% width of the form it is in not of itself. They are inline @Beartech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `width: calc(100% /  7)` along with `display:inline-block`, for a equal division between those 7 `input`s

---

```css
.collection_check_boxes {
  width: calc(100% / 7);
  display: inline-block;
  background:red
}
```

```html
<div class="challenge-do-on">

  <span><label for="challenge_committed_sun"><input type="checkbox" value="sun" checked="checked" name="challenge[committed][]" id="challenge_committed_sun"><label class="collection_check_boxes"for="challenge_committed_sun">Sun</label></label></span>

  <span><label for="challenge_committed_mon"><input type="checkbox" value="mon" checked="checked" name="challenge[committed][]" id="challenge_committed_mon"><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="challenge_committed_mon">Mon</label></label></span>

  <span><label for="challenge_committed_tue"><input type="checkbox" value="tue" checked="checked" name="challenge[committed][]" id="challenge_committed_tue"><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="challenge_committed_tue">Tue</label></label></span>

  <span><label for="challenge_committed_wed"><input type="checkbox" value="wed" checked="checked" name="challenge[committed][]" id="challenge_committed_wed"><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="challenge_committed_wed">Wed</label></label></span>

  <span><label for="challenge_committed_thu"><input type="checkbox" value="thu" checked="checked" name="challenge[committed][]" id="challenge_committed_thu"><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="challenge_committed_thu">Thu</label></label></span>

  <span><label for="challenge_committed_fri"><input type="checkbox" value="fri" checked="checked" name="challenge[committed][]" id="challenge_committed_fri"><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="challenge_committed_fri">Fri</label></label></span>

  <span><label for="challenge_committed_sat"><input type="checkbox" value="sat" checked="checked" name="challenge[committed][]" id="challenge_committed_sat"><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="challenge_committed_sat">Sat</label></label></span>

</div>
```

In case if you want to keep the `18%`, here is a **snippet**

---

```css
.collection_check_boxes {
  width: 18%;
  display: inline-block;
  background:red
}
```

```html
<div class="challenge-do-on">

  <span><label for="challenge_committed_sun"><input type="checkbox" value="sun" checked="checked" name="challenge[committed][]" id="challenge_committed_sun"><label class="collection_check_boxes"for="challenge_committed_sun">Sun</label></label></span>

  <span><label for="challenge_committed_mon"><input type="checkbox" value="mon" checked="checked" name="challenge[committed][]" id="challenge_committed_mon"><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="challenge_committed_mon">Mon</label></label></span>

  <span><label for="challenge_committed_tue"><input type="checkbox" value="tue" checked="checked" name="challenge[committed][]" id="challenge_committed_tue"><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="challenge_committed_tue">Tue</label></label></span>

  <span><label for="challenge_committed_wed"><input type="checkbox" value="wed" checked="checked" name="challenge[committed][]" id="challenge_committed_wed"><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="challenge_committed_wed">Wed</label></label></span>

  <span><label for="challenge_committed_thu"><input type="checkbox" value="thu" checked="checked" name="challenge[committed][]" id="challenge_committed_thu"><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="challenge_committed_thu">Thu</label></label></span>

  <span><label for="challenge_committed_fri"><input type="checkbox" value="fri" checked="checked" name="challenge[committed][]" id="challenge_committed_fri"><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="challenge_committed_fri">Fri</label></label></span>

  <span><label for="challenge_committed_sat"><input type="checkbox" value="sat" checked="checked" name="challenge[committed][]" id="challenge_committed_sat"><label class="collection_check_boxes" for="challenge_committed_sat">Sat</label></label></span>

</div>
```